# Store ajax request for further use in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is my scenario.

1. I send a request before login and the server tell me to login.
2. And I hope to send the request before login automatically after I login.

So how can I store the request and trigger it again after login?

Comment: did not understood the flow, but why don't you use a Cookie to save something for the next time you need?

Comment: The answer below described the solution :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
var request = {
    url : 'somehandler.php',
    data : parameters,
    success: function(){
        // handler for success
    },
    error : function(){
        // handler for error
    }
};
```

Then you store the request options in the variable request, which you can reuse later like so:

```
$.ajax(request);
```

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense and it is quite easy. I always think it may be more complicated. Thanks a lot.